# Trying to Loop through Google Maps Address Components

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Why is this not working??? I can't loop through the address components returned from the google map api.

```
if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
        var arrAddress = results[0].address_components;
        console.log(arrAddress);
        //iterate through address_component array
        $.each(arrAddress, function (i, address_component) {
             console.log('address_component:'+i); 
             if (address_component.types[0] == "locality"){
                        console.log("town:"+address_component.long_name);

                    }
    });
}
 }
```

Comment: Could be about a billion reasons...they'll be narrowed down substantially if you could provide us with an error message.

Comment: it says undefined in the console when trying to output address_component.long_name. Additionally in the console when I output arrAddress I only get one result instead of the whole array.

Comment: REALLY SORRY...now it is working for some reason. Not even sure why yet...have tried so many different things.

Comment: @Brian Just a thought have you read the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) for geocoding. and you might have to deal with other status coded especially **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**